# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module on importing MuiOtpInput

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, eslint

When deploying my Next.js project on Vercel, I encountered a

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

when trying to `import { MuiOtpInput } from "mui-one-time-password-input"`. Despite attempting to disable ESLint, the issue persists. Is there an alternative way to import or another solution to resolve this error?

Comment: Seems like a webpack issue. Can you share a code snippet? Where you are using this